# getting Gii to work on Yii 2.0

Tags: php, crud, yii2, gii

i downloaded the advanced template, extracted it and changed the root documents for the back-end and the front-end, but i can't seem to figure out how to get Gii working to perform the crud operations.

there is require and require-dev field in the composer.JSON i included gii in both of them and each one separately with no luck.

i also tried getting the template through composer, and while installing i saw gii as installed, but still could not get it to work.

this is where i got my Yii template: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Comment: and how do you call gii? it must work by default.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the  exact same issue. The only difference is I installed everything via composer.

Comment: @synapze yes i did, i'm sorry i did not provide an answer. i had this 'modules' => ['gii' => 'yii\gii\Module'], missing from my backend/config/main.php. my project is in backend, if yours is somewhere else put this accordingly.

Comment: What's the error you get? Can you open gii? Is the CRUD generator the only stuff which is not working? Are you accessing it from localhost?

Answer (score 21):

This is how to get Gii working from a remote server for an advanced setup template.

In the frontend config file. For example:

```
/frontend/config/main-local.php
```

Add the following code:

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii']=[
      'class' =>  'yii\gii\Module',
      'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
    ];
}
```

The interesting part is the Gii `array` which has been modified.

Comment: i have doen this but i keep getting `Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The configuration for the "bootstrap" component must contain a "class" element.`

Comment: @bonez Can you paste your config file?

Answer (score 11):

Step 1: Add Following line to required-dev of composer.json

```
"yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*"
```

Step 2: Update your composer.
Step 3: Add Following line to your frontend/config/main.php file. Don't incude these ..........

```
  'modules' => [
    ............
    'gii' => [
      'class' => 'yii\gii\Module', //adding gii module
      'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1']  //allowing ip's 
    ],
    ...........
  ]
```

Step 4:
If you have enabled your clean url then go to

```
project_name/frontend/web/gii
```

if not then go to

```
project_name/frontend/web/index.php?r=gii
```

You can follow the link [yii2_gii](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii)

Comment: i have doen this but i keep getting `Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The configuration for the "modules" component must contain a "class" element.`

Comment: When you generated you application before or after the yii2 release?

Answer (score 6):

Like described [in the Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html) you have to adjust the allowed IPs in the **/frontend/config/main-local.php**:

```
    if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
      ...
      $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
      $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.*.*']
      ];
    }
```

If you have modified your **/frontend/config/main.php** like this for pretty URLs:

```
    return [
    ...
    'components' => [
      ...
      'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false
      ],
      ...
    ];
```

You can call gii with the URL

```
    yourVM.local/gii
```

(Having *yourVM.local* point to your Frontend Module in your Hosts file.)

Answer (score 2):

Also, try this if `gii` still does not work:

This should be well documented by the yii team!

After I used the `init` command, in `/frontend/config/main-local.php`, I found:

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}
```

My app is in `dev` mode, and te above declaration, stops my `gii` to work, so ... comment that line

Answer (score 1):

I had to comment out the urlManager element (disabling pretty Urls) in 'components' in the relevant config file (actually commented out by default).

```
backend/config/main.php
```

Before disabling pretty Urls I could load the Gii page, but when attemtping to load any of the generator pages (Controller, Model, etc.) I was redirected to the home page.