# Yii How to get to Crud Generator

Tags: php, yii, yii2, crud

Need help! How can I go to CRUD generator in yii?

I just created my application but when I try entering localhost/myapp/index.php?r=gii it says that "Unable to resolve the request gii"

Anyone? PLease help me. THanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_VMsi4fA6k

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102922/getting-gii-to-work-on-yii-2-0

Comment: Thanks! @Deepaksaini!

Comment: btw, what is the default password?

Comment: alright. thanks again! why im downvoted? :(

Comment: I don't know. But I have upvoted for you

Comment: thanks! I can't figure out what's with the password? it says incorrect.

Comment: I got it. I should type it on the page. thanks @Deepaksaini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to config->main.php and uncomment to gii.

```
'modules'=>array(
         'gii'=>array(
             'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
              'password'=>'Enter your password here',
              'ipFilters'=>array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
        ),
    ),
```