# How to activate Gii Code Generator in Yii 2.0.6?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php

I have updated my yii version using composer which is 2.0.6. When i try to locate Gii, Yii through 404 Not Found Error.

Screen Shot:

[image]

Composer.json File:

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
}
```

Frontend/config/main-local.php:

```
    <?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '69PNggqfArD-9mR7H9lM3M0SaEBJD9Dr',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Can anyone tell me how to activate Gii in  yii2 2.0.6?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102922/getting-gii-to-work-on-yii-2-0

Comment: you should be change /frontend/config/main-local.php please view link

Comment: show `/frontend/config/main-local.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

1. First I need to change environment mode from web index.php

   ```
   `defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');`
   ```
2. Then update `main-local.php` file:

   ```
   $config = [
       'components' => [
           'request' => [
               // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
               'cookieValidationKey' => '69PNggqfArD-9mR7H9lM3M0SaEBJD9Dr',
           ],
       ],
   ];

   if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
       // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
       $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
       $config['modules']['debug'] = [
           'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
       ];
       $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
       $config['modules']['gii'] = [
           'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
       ];
   }

   return $config;
   ```

It is working now

Answer (score 2):

Change your code in  `/frontend/config/main-local.php` to:

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => '69PNggqfArD-9mR7H9lM3M0SaEBJD9Dr',
        ],
    ],
];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```